# Referencing Entity Attribute in Swift 3 (Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm following a very simple swift course and while everything works for the instructor the same code does not execute on my side and I'm trying to understand why is that happening.

The app is very simple, is consists of adding tasks to a TableView with a name and a switch to determine if those are important (in which case an emoji is added to the name)

While trying to access and modify the "name" attribute of my "Taskentity" core data entity, the editor gives me the error "Value of type "Taskentity" has no member "name"".

The code is the following :

```
import UIKit

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var isImp: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let task = Taskentity(context: context)
    task.name = textField.text! // **!error!**

    task.isImportant = isImp.isOn

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

}

And my Core Data file looks like this :
[image: Core Data file]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen shot shows the problem perfectly. You have named the attribute `corename`, not `name`. So naturally the name `name` is not its name!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with you attributes. The one titled 'corename' which is a string should be renamed to 'name' Xcode cannot tell what .name means because you have nothing that Devi gets what it is.

I have attached how your code should look to fix this problem:

```
import UIKit

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var isImp: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!     AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let task = Taskentity(context: context)
task.corename = textField.text! // **!error!**

task.isImportant = isImp.isOn

(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```